# zsh: command not found: mongod, unable to use mongodb

Tags: mongodb, macos, terminal

I have installed mongodb and was trying to run with macbook zsh:

```
mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

But I get this error:

```
zsh: command not found: mongod
```

I have tried these stack overflow answers and it didnt work.

1. I followed the same tutorial, why do I receive this message, but others don't?
2. What is the reason for this error?
3. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed mongo correctly then it is likely not reachable via your PATH variable. I would recommend following the official mongodb instructions for installing mongo using homebrew.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Once that is done you should be able to restart your terminal and be able to run the command provided.